# How to represent E(Y|X) in terms of E(X), E(Y), Var(X), Cov(X,Y)?

Tags: probability

Known things are:
E(Y|X)=aX+b, 
Cov(X,Y) exists,
0 < Var(X) < Infinity,

Question:
Represent a,b in terms of E(X), E(Y), Var(X), Cov(X,Y)

I worked out only one equation: E[E(Y|X)]=E(Y)=E(aX+b)=aE(x)+b, i.e. aE(X)+b=E(Y).
But in order to represent a and b another equation is needed.
Please help me, thanks~

Comment: Notice that the question limited representations using E(X) E(Y) Var(X) Cov(X,Y), no Var(Y) could be used

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu_X=E[x]$ and $\mu_Y=E[Y]$. This is the other equation
$$
\begin{split}
\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) &= E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)]\\
&= E[E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)|X]]\\
&= E[(X-\mu_X)E[(Y-\mu_Y)|X]]\\
&= E[(X-\mu_X)(aX+b-\mu_Y)]\\
&= E[(X-\mu_X)(aX-a\mu_X)]\\
&= aE[(X-\mu_X)^2]\\
&= a\operatorname{Var}(X),
\end{split}
$$
where we have used the fact that $\mu_Y=a\mu_X+b$.

So
$$
E[Y|X] = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)}{\operatorname{Var}(X)}(X-\mu_X)+\mu_Y.
$$

Comment: You can get proper formatting for operators like $\operatorname{Cov}$ and $\operatorname{Var}$ using e.g. `\operatorname{Cov}`.

Comment: Done. But I find it surprising that tex has \cot but not \cov which is far more useful. Sometimes I drop \operatorname just to convey my annoyance!

Comment: But we're not suitable targets of your annoyance :-)

Comment: You have left me no choice but agreeing with you

Comment: Thanks so much! It's such a creative way of thinking

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You already worked out half of the answer:

$$E[E(Y|X)]=E(Y)=E(aX+b)=aE(x)+b \implies  aE(X)+b=E(Y)$$

Additionally:

$$E [X \, E [Y|X] =E[E[X Y |Y]]=E[XY]=Cov(X,Y)+E[Y][X]$$
but
$$E [X \, E [Y|X]] =E[X (aX+b)]=a E[X^2]+b E[X]=a (Var(X)+E[X]^2)+b E[X]$$

Combining these two equations, and together with the one above, you can get $a$ and $b$

Comment: Wow that's really a useful formula to know. Thank you leonbloy:)

Comment: I wouldn't call that "a formula to know",  it's actually the tower property (or law of iterated expectations) in its general form: $E[ E[g(X,Y)| Y]] = E[g(X,Y)]$

Comment: Thanks^__^ so nice that you could give me this introduction!